# Share Operating system image across subscriptions?

Tags: azure

We have a number of subscriptions and would like to share a OperationSystem image across subscriptions? How do I make this happen?

The underlying vhd of the blob is also publicly accessible. So it there are not options with the images can I do something at the disk leve?

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a programming question. That being said, the answer looks like the following, with the PowerShell commands in parentheses:

1. Install the Microsoft Azure PowerShell module
2. Authenticate to Microsoft Azure using an account that has access to both source and target subscriptions (`Add-AzureAccount`)
3. Select the source subscription (`Select-AzureSubscription`)
4. Retrieve a Storage Context for the source subscription (`Get-AzureStorageKey` + `New-AzureStorageContext`)
5. Select the target subscription (`Select-AzureSubscription`)
6. Retrieve a Storage Context for the target subscription (`Get-AzureStorageKey` + `New-AzureStorageContext`)
7. Copy the Azure blob from a Storage Account in the source subscription to a Storage Account in the target subscription (`Start-AzureStorageBlobCopy`)
8. Register the image in the target subscription (`Add-AzureVMImage`)

**NOTE**: Azure Virtual Machine images cannot be shared across Azure platform subscriptions, except for Linux and BSD images in the VM Depot. You must make a copy of the image into each Azure subscription.

Comment: This appears to be a "copy" image instead of a "share" image. I am already aware on how to do this and I don't want to do this as this will involve maintaining mutiple copies of the the image. I'm looking for  "share" option where a single image/vhd can be shared across subscriptions.

Comment: That's not possible today, except through the VM Depot, which I mentioned. This method does not support Windows operating system images, however.